# Aggregation json elements by sub-string

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "name": "a-v1",
        "date": "2018-05-08T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "a-v2",
        "date": "2018-05-20T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "a-v3",
        "date": "2018-05-22T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "b-v1",
        "date": "2018-02-08T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "b-v2",
        "date": "2018-05-08T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "b-v3",
        "date": "2018-05-10T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "c-v1",
        "date": "2018-10-08T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "c-v2",
        "date": "2018-11-08T08:40:35.000Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "d-v1",
        "date": "2018-08-08T08:40:35.000Z"
    }
]
```

Each `name` combines from type and version (In `a-v1` for example, a in the type and v1 is the version).

How can i create a list of all the `name` which are not the 2 latest versions?
In our case, The output would be:

```
a-v1
b-v1
```

Any idea how to do that in Python? I've been thinking about counting sub-strings. For example: To use `-` as a delimiter, And count how many times i find the left side of the string (aa, b, c). Is this possible to implement such as thing in Python? Any better ideas?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the approach you proposed .

Comment: The output should contain also a-v3,d-v1,... ? why only a-v1 and b-v1?

Comment: or you may use something like priority queue with limit size, maybe overkill I think.

Comment: @newbie I have 3 versions of `a`, And i want to keep only the 2 latest version, So and output would be `a-v1` (Which is the oldest version). Same as for `b`. As for `c` and `d`, I don't have more than 2 versions of each, So the output would be empty for them.

Comment: do you sort by postfix like `v1` or you account for dates as well? do you need to check the order of v-somehting is in proper date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list `L` is pre-sorted, as in your example, you can use `itertools.groupby` and use list slicing:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouper = groupby(map(itemgetter('name'), L), key=lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
groups = (list(vals)[:-2] for _, vals in grouper)

res = list(chain.from_iterable(filter(None, groups)))

# ['a-v1', 'b-v1']
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. My use case has been changed. Should i open a new question or update the current one? The new use case supposed the be much easier, But i still have some issues.

Comment: @Omri, You should open a new question since you already have a couple of answers here. If you've checked any of the solutions on this one, feel free to accept one so other users know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem would be easier with a slightly different data format.

You didn't write any code so I won't give you a complete answer:

```
data = [{'name': 'a-v1', 'date': '2018-05-08T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'a-v2', 'date': '2018-05-20T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'a-v3', 'date': '2018-05-22T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'b-v1', 'date': '2018-02-08T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'b-v2', 'date': '2018-05-08T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'b-v3', 'date': '2018-05-10T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'c-v1', 'date': '2018-10-08T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'c-v2', 'date': '2018-11-08T08:40:35.000Z'}, {'name': 'd-v1', 'date': '2018-08-08T08:40:35.000Z'}]
temp = [d['name'].split('-') for d in data]
# [['a', 'v1'], ['a', 'v2'], ['a', 'v3'], ['b', 'v1'], ['b', 'v2'], ['b', 'v3'], ['c', 'v1'], ['c', 'v2'], ['d', 'v1']]
versions = [(letter, int(v[1:])) for letter, v in temp]
sorted(versions)
```

It outputs:

```
[('a', 1),
 ('a', 2),
 ('a', 3),
 ('b', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 3),
 ('c', 1),
 ('c', 2),
 ('d', 1)]
```

You could now try to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the versions by letter and remove every version but the last two ones for each group.